# In Python, how do I create a dataframe3 made up of rows in dataframe2 that does match entries of dataframe1?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'num': [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9],
                   'lower': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'j'],
                   'char': ['!', '(', '$', '+', '^', '^', ')'],
                   'upper': ['Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'U', 'T']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'num': range(0,10),
                   'lower': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
                   'char': ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')'],
                   'upper': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']})
```

I would like to make a df3 consisting of rows of df2 that do not match the num, lower, AND char columns seen in df1. The upper column is inconsequential to constructing df3, though important to have in the data frame.

I iterated over the two dataframes using itertuples() to get the indices for the rows that had common entries for the 3 columns. Then, I got the indices not in that list and made the data frame using the loc method. The code is shown below:

```
commonEntries = []
for row in df1.itertuples():
    for line in df2.itertuples():
        if row[df1.columns.get_loc('num')+1] == line[df2.columns.get_loc('num')+1] and row[df1.columns.get_loc('lower')+1] == line[df2.columns.get_loc('lower')+1] and row[df1.columns.get_loc('char')+1] == line[df2.columns.get_loc('char')+1]:
            commonEntries.append(line[0])

goodGuys = [x for x in df2.index if x not in commonEntries]
goodEntries = df2.loc[goodGuys]
```

I got the desired output and what I expected:

[image]

But this code seems not good, especially if I am going through thousands of rows in each dataframe.

I imagine that you can also concat the data frames and drop_duplicates on the subsets of interest. However, if there are rows in df2 that share the same num, lower, and char, I would eliminate those, but I want to keep them if they don't match entries in df1. Some combo of concat, join, or merge with drop_duplicates feels like the best way, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick, is relatively simple and mostly easy to read:

```py
idx = (
    pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True)
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['num', 'char', 'lower'], keep='last')
).index
df3 = df2.loc[idx.intersection(df2.index)]

assert np.array_equal(df3.index, np.array([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]))
```

Comment: `pd.Index` has an `.intersection` method, so you don't need the `np.intersect1d`: `idx = idx.intersection(df2.index)` should do the same job.

Comment: @Timus Thanks. Edited answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach with `.merge` instead of `pd.concat`:

```py
df3 = df2[df2.merge(df1, on=["num", "char", "lower"], how="left")["upper_y"].isna()]
```

`.merge` `df1` on `df2` with `how="left"` on the columns `num`, `char`, and `lower`: `df2` keeps all rows and the new `upper_y` column is `NaN` when there's no match in `df1`. Then build a mask based on the `NaN`s in `upper_y` and apply it to the original `df2`.

Result:

```
   num lower char upper
1    1     b    @     B
2    2     c    #     C
4    4     e    %     E
6    6     g    &     G
7    7     h    *     H
8    8     i    (     I
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is:

```py
df1 = df1.drop(columns='upper')

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.drop(columns='upper')], ignore_index=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df3, df1], ignore_index=True)

df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
merged = df3.merge(df2[['num', 'lower', 'char', 'upper']], on=['num', 'lower', 'char'], how='left')
```

However, this solution will use much more space than your solution. May be a problem for bigger dataframes.